# OpenCV C++: Create Column Range for Mat type data from indices stored in int vector

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Some (discontinuous)indices are stored in a vector `vec`. Given a `Mat` type `data`, how to create a subset of data with only those columns whose indices are specified in the vector `vec`?
For rows, I can specify `Range::all()`; but I couldn't specify column range for this subset.

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 4, 7, 13, 21, 51, 87};
cv::Mat data, subData;
subData= data(Range::all(), colRange); //Not sure, what to write in place of colRange
```

Comment: You can't use indices like that. You need to loop over `vec` and deep copy needed columns

Comment: I didn't expect that. When we say `Range(start, end)`, a sequence of numbers from start to end is represented(wrapped) by an object of type Range. Is it not possible to remove some elements from this Range object ?

Comment: No, because then you won't have a Range anymore, but a set of sub-Ranges. But you just need to copy the desired columns to a new matrix, that can be implemented quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Miki, I did the following:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < vec.size(); index++)
        data.col(vec[index]).copyTo(subData.col(index)); //loop over the vector, copy the data from vec[index] column to subData[index]
```